# Why does trigger create two projects in production but not in sandbox?

Tags: apex, trigger, duplicate-management, help

I've created this trigger to create a project upon an opportunity being closed won.  In our sandbox the trigger is performing properly.  However, in production it is creating two projects for one opportunity.  Can someone help me figure out why?

```
 trigger AddProject on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {    
 if(trigger.isUpdate){
        set<string> setOfFields = new set<string>{
                    'Generate_Projects__c', 'StageName', 'Projects_Created__c'
                };
        boolean change = false;
        for (integer i = 0; i < Trigger.new.size(); i++) {
            for (string field : setOfFields){
                if(trigger.new[i].get(field) != trigger.old[i].get(field)){
                    change = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(change){
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!change){
            return;
        }
    }

    Set<Id> SetOfIds = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> SetOfOPLIIds = new Set<Id>();
    list<Project__c> lstProject = new List<Project__c>();
    list<CreditDetail__c> lstCD = new List<CreditDetail__c>();
    list<map<Date,Project__c>> lstmapProjects = new List<map<Date,Project__c>>();
    boolean blnContinue = false; 

    for (Integer i = 0; i < Trigger.new.size(); i++) {   
        if (Trigger.new[i].Generate_Projects__c == true && Trigger.new[i].StageName == '7 - Closed Won' && Trigger.new[i].Projects_Created__c == false){
            blnContinue=true;
        }
        SetOfIds.add(Trigger.new[i].Id);
    }

    if (!blnContinue) {
        return;
    }

    for (Integer i = 0; i < Trigger.new.size(); i++) {
        SetOfIds.add(Trigger.new[i].Id);
    }

    list<Opportunity> OppList = [Select Id,OwnerId, Generate_Projects__c, Beneficiary__c,Contract_New__c, RecordType.name, AccountId, Name, StageName, Projects_Created__c, 
    (Select Id, ProductID__c, Description, Jurisdiction__c,Tax_Years__c, TotalPrice, Product_ID__c, Budget_Month__c, Budget_Year__c, ServiceDate, Quantity From OpportunityLineItems) From Opportunity where id IN :SetOfIds 
    and StageName='7 - Closed Won' and RecordType.name = 'Research & Development'];

    for (Integer i = 0; i < OppList.size(); i++) {
        lstmapProjects.add(new map<Date,Project__c>());
        if (OppList[i].StageName == '7 - Closed Won' && OppList[i].RecordType.name == 'Research & Development' && Opplist[i].Generate_Projects__c == true){

            for (integer j = 0; j < OppList[i].OpportunityLineItems.size(); j++){
                if (lstmapProjects[i].get(OppList[i].OpportunityLineItems[j].ServiceDate) == null) {
                    lstmapProjects[i].put(OppList[i].OpportunityLineItems[j].ServiceDate, 
                    new Project__c (Kickoff_Date__c = OppList[i].OpportunityLineItems[j].ServiceDate,
                                    Project_Stage__c='1 - Awaiting Start - Internal',
                                    Program_Type__c = 'Research & Development',
                                    PlatformContract__c=OppList[i].Contract_New__c,
                                    Delivery_Deadline__c=OppList[i].OpportunityLineItems[j].ServiceDate+90,
                                    Opportunity__c = OppList[i].Id,
                                    Account__c = OppList[i].AccountId,
                                    Name = OppList[i].Name   + string.valueOf(OppList[i].OpportunityLineItems[j].ServiceDate.Year()) + '-'+ string.valueOf(OppList[i].OpportunityLineItems[j].ServiceDate.Year()+1)));
                    lstProject.add(lstmapProjects[i].get(OppList[i].OpportunityLineItems[j].ServiceDate));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    update OppList;
    insert lstProject;

    for (Integer i = 0; i < OppList.size(); i++) {
        if (OppList[i].StageName == '7 - Closed Won' && OppList[i].RecordType.name == 'Research & Development' && Opplist[i].Generate_Projects__c == true) {
            for (Integer j = 0; j < OppList[i].OpportunityLineItems.size(); j++) {
                //system.debug(OppList[i].OpportunityLineItems[j].Event_Quantity__c);

                if(lstmapProjects[i].get(OppList[i].OpportunityLineItems[j].ServiceDate) != null){
                  lstCD.add(new CreditDetail__c( Name =OppList[i].AccountID+'_'+'R&D'+ OppList[i].OpportunityLineItems[j].Jurisdiction__c+'_'+OppList[i].OpportunityLineItems[j].Tax_Years__c,
                                                 Product__c = OppList[i].OpportunityLineItems[j].Product_ID__c,
                                                 Project__c = lstmapProjects[i].get(OppList[i].OpportunityLineItems[j].ServiceDate).Id,
                                                 Beneficiary__c = OppList[i].Beneficiary__c,
                                                RecordTypeId = '01214000001FsPI',
                                                Jurisdiction__c = OppList[i].OpportunityLineItems[j].Jurisdiction__c,
                                                Program__c = 'R&D',
                                                Forecast_Credits_Delivered__c = OppList[i].OpportunityLineItems[j].TotalPrice,
                                                ForecastCreditDeliveredMonth__c = OppList[i].OpportunityLineItems[j].Budget_Month__c,
                                                ForecastCreditsDeliveredYear__c = OppList[i].OpportunityLineItems[j].Budget_Year__c,
                                                Tax_Year__c = OppList[i].OpportunityLineItems[j].Tax_Years__c));
                }

            }
        }
    }
    insert lstCD;
```

Comment: What field update workflow rules do you have active in each environment?

Comment: I have multiple field updates on both opportunity & opp Product.

Comment: Are they identical in both environments? My first guess would be that the sandbox doesn't update a field when the opportunity becomes closed won while production does.

Answer (score 0):

workflow Rules cause triggers to run twice. You might want to modify your trigger to make sure you'll avoid creating duplicates:

```
trigger X on Opportunity (...) {
    if(staticVariables.triggerIds.containsAll(Trigger.newMap.keySet()) {
        return;
    }
    staticVariables.triggerIds.addAll(Trigger.newMap.keySet());
    // Do the rest of your code here
```

The variable is a simple normal class:

```
public class staticVariables {
    public static Set<Id> triggerIds = new Set<Id>();
}
```

Comment: I've added the above and created the new staticvariables class.  Still getting the duplicate issue.

Comment: Hmm. I'm out of ideas. You might need some debug logs. Triggers should only execute twice at most.